# Changing the value of input

Tags: jquery

How to change the value of `<input id="myinput">`?

sample:

```
value - page.html
will be - page\.html

value - abc.php
will be - abc\.php
```

Comment: Entering your question title into Google and adding "jquery" gives the answer.

Comment: You want to append backslash before the first `.` character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

```
$("#elm").val("new value");
```

and replace contents like this:

```
var oldval = $("#elm").val();
oldval = oldval.replace(/\./g,"\\.")
$("#elm").val(oldval);
```

Comment: Actually `oldval.replace(/\./g, "\\.")`

Comment: Thanks, I understand the principle :)